# How to link a container already running to my app using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I need to link 2 containers named **proxy1** and **proxy2** to **myapp**.

**proxy1** and **proxy2** are using a docker command to run, and **myapp** is using a docker-compose.yml

I need to be able to ping **proxy1** and **proxy2** from the container **myapp**

I tried to use `external_links` in my docker-compose.yml like that:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    external_links:
      - proxy1
      - proxy2
```

if i make a `docker ps` i have this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
2f0365826670        myapp         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp   myapp_myapp_1
bbd1f5340086        proxy         "supervisord -n"         Up 2 hours          127.0.0.1:5002->8080/tcp                         proxy2
6c3cd1eb6530        proxy         "supervisord -n"         Up 2 hours          127.0.0.1:5001->8080/tcp                         proxy1
```

How can i access to these 2 proxy containers from myapp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do the following:

create a network:

```
docker network create mynetwork
```

connect your standalone container to the network:

```
docker network connect mynetwork my_container
```

update your docker-compose:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: mynetwork
```

Other way is to check what the standalone contaoner network is using:

```
docker inspect proxy1
```

and use that netwok as the external network in compose.

or you can use the `network_mode: "host"` in your compose which is not recommended

Comment: when i try to do `docker network connect mynetwork proxy1` 

i get this error : 

`Error response from daemon: failed to add interface veth984accd to sandbox: error setting interface "veth984accd" IP to 172.19.0.4/16: cannot program address 172.19.0.4/16 in sandbox interface because it conflicts with existing route {Ifindex: 2 Dst: 128.0.0.0/1 Src: <nil> Gw: 100.124.176.1 Flags: [] Table: 254}`

Comment: you can use existing network of proxy1 if you want in your compose check it  using `docker inspect  proxy1`

Comment: ok super, when i `docker inspect proxy1` i get `"Networks": { "bridge": {...` so i used `bridge` as a `network-mode` in my docker-compose.yml, but how do i ping my proxy1 from myapp

Comment: i used `network_mode: host`, this is the best solution for my problem